# Android/Java - Set and compare date with offset

Tags: android, time, compare, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an app which fetches data from a webpage which is updated at 9pm (In AEDT time) each day.
The data is stored using shared preferences after it is fetched.

Since it would be pointless to fetch the data if we know the page hasn't been updated since the last time it was fetched, I'm trying to implement the following:

1) when data is fetched, set a timestamp preference value of the current time
2) when the app would fetch data, check if the current time is "after the next 9pm of the last fetch date"
3) if so, fetch data, otherwise show message saying it doesn't need updating.

I'm not sure how to store the current date as a primitive that can be stored in shared preferences... Perhaps System.currentTimeMillis() (returns a long)?  This is returned in UTC... will need to make sure that all setting and checking is done with the same timezone...

How do I then check if the current time is past the update threshold of "the next 9pm"?

(As a failsafe, the user has a menu button to force an update - which will be mentioned if the app determines an update is not needed.)

**EDIT:  I think I've solved it, but would still appreciate any feedback or suggestions - see below.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case, you will need to implement a service in your app. Just make sure you don't run unnecessary code in your service or the user's battery will take a hit! Please refer to this page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: I'm not sure I see how a service would help...  The app currently attempts to fetch data when it is started.  I want to incorporate a check at that point that tests whether it is worth doing so or not (i.e. if the page would have been updated since the timestamp of the last update).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a solution.

When data is fetched, the following is done...

```
editPrefs.putLong("fetchTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

When the application starts and data is normally requested, it now does..
(**Note:**  The page is updated daily at "9pm AEDT" - (Australia Eastern Daylight Savings time), and I assume it would change to AEST (Australia Eastern Standard time) when daylight savings ends.  "Australia/ACT" is a timezone that goes by these zones)

```
//create calendar date for update threshold based on last fetch time preference
Calendar updateThresh = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/ACT"));
updateThresh.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong("fetchTime", 0));

//increment day if last fetch was >= 9pm of that day
if (updateThresh.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 21)
    updateThresh.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

//set time to 9:00:00pm
updateThresh.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY , 21);
updateThresh.set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0);
updateThresh.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);

//check if current date is before or after
if (updateThresh.before(new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/ACT"))))
{
    //update needed (fetch data)
}
else
{
    //update not needed (show message)
}
```

This seems to work fine. I've tested it using a DateFormat set to Australia/ACT and it seems to work... e.g. Making another calendar object that is set to the fetch time and using:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/ACT"));

testTextField.setText("Last fetch in East AU time: " + df.format(fetchTime.getTimeInMillis()) + 
    "\nUpdate threshold in East AU time: " + df.format(updateThresh.getTimeInMillis()) );
```

This shows me consistently correct output even if I play around with the timezone settings on my phone...  I'm fairly certain this solution works, so I'll mark it correct/accepted - but if anyone notices an error or has a better suggestion, feel free to contribute! :)

Comment: why not make Calendar constant with 9 p.m. australian time and compare current time with that time?

Comment: Isn't that essentially what I've done?  I'm not sure that just "9pm Australian time" would work, since it needs to be either the current or next day...